# Dynamically Rename SQL Field Column Names with Special Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database with tables imported from excel csv files.  There are some tables that have field names with special characters like a space, /, $, #, % among others.

Is there a way to dynamically look at every field column name in every table and replace the special character with an underscore, some other string (for example: replace % with PCT or # with NBR or $ with CUR) or even delete the character all together?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you only importing the data once?  Bc if you rename the columns, your next import will be complicated.  Also, is it too late to rename those columns when you import them, or did that already happen and its too late now?

Comment: Running SQL Server Version 2017.

Comment: There will be multiple imports.  Each time I will create a new database.  It is not practical to change the column names in every csv table prior to the import.

Comment: How do you import? Using SQL Server, using excel, using a script ???

Comment: @ThomasG I am using an Azure Data Factory pipeline to load the csv files from an Azure storage account and copy them into corresponding tables in an Azure SQL database